# Find the distributed accumulation function of $X$ where $X^3\sim U(1,8)$

Tags: probability, statistics

For a random variable $X$ it's known that $X^3$ is uniform distributed in range $[1,8]$, Find the distributed accumulation function of $X$.

*Attempt:*

$X^3\sim U(1,8)$

$F(t^3)=$Pr$(X^3\leqslant t^3)$

$\implies F(t^3)=\begin{cases}0,&t^3\leqslant 0\\
\frac{t^3-1}{8-1},& 1<t^3<8\\
1,& t^3>8\end{cases}$

Taking the third root:

$\implies F(t)=\begin{cases}\color{red}0,&t\leqslant 0\\
\color{red}{\frac{t^3-1}{8-1}},& 1<t<2\\
\color{red}1,& t>8\end{cases}$

Should I take the third root from the red also? i.e this will be the answer:

$\implies F(t)=\begin{cases}\sqrt[3]{0},&t\leqslant 0\\
\sqrt[3]{\frac{t^3-1}{8-1}},& 1<t<2\\
\sqrt[3]1,& t>8\end{cases}$

Comment: You think that $$F(t^3)=\frac{t^3-1}{8-1}$$ and also that $$F(t)=\frac{t^3-1}{8-1}$$ and also that $$F(t)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{t^3-1}{8-1}}$$ all three simultaneously? Come on...

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the third root"? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X^3$ has uniform distribution on $[1,8]$ so:$$F_{X^{3}}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }t<1\\
\frac{1}{7}\left(t-1\right) & \text{if }1\leq t\leq8\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Applying: $$F_X(t)=P(X\leq t)=P(X^3\leq t^3)=F_{X^3}(t^3)$$we find:$$F_{X}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }t^3<1\\
\frac{1}{7}\left(t^{3}-1\right) & \text{if }1\leq t^3\leq8\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

leading to:$$F_{X}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }t<1\\
\frac{1}{7}\left(t^{3}-1\right) & \text{if }1\leq t\leq2\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$